# Create xsd for xaml objects

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Is there a library function in the .Net framework to create xml schema definitions for xaml objects?
Or is it possible to steer xsd.exe's behaviour, so it will create these schema definitions?

Answer (score 1):

XAML is a subset of XML (as far as I know), so I think you would be fine with `XmlSchemaInference` class.

See my question:

[XmlSchema inferred from an XML file - how to iterate through all the elements in the XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311880/xmlschema-inferred-from-an-xml-file-how-to-iterate-through-all-the-elements-in/7324613#7324613) (I answered it myself)

as well as:

[Generating an XSD file with xsd.exe tool from an XML file with multiple namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210589/generating-an-xsd-file-with-xsd-exe-tool-from-an-xml-file-with-multiple-namespac)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I will have a look on it. Maybee I will use  XamlType's for creating the schema instead of XmlSchemaInterference.